# Protect URL from non-authenticated users without login prompt?

Tags: apache-2.4, authentication

I'm trying to protect a web application (a Kibana dashboard) which has no built-in user authentication process. I would like to protect this web application so that only users who are logged into our WordPress site can open the web application URL, without prompting them to re-authenticate.

the environment:

Apache 2.4 on Centos 7

I've extensively looked into all of the areas I'm familiar with: I've tried to use Apache mod_authnz_external which uses a local perl script for authentication. This does what I want, but, I can't get around the login prompt - which is a deal breaker.

I've tried using mod_rewrite and rewriteMap to redirect the Kibana URLs to a local Perl script to check authentication. This works, but then I can't figure out how to then pass the user back to the redirected URL without triggering the original rewrite match.......

I have setup a reverse proxy for Kibana and I could use that to control access, but I can't figure out if there is way to use an Apache proxy to authenticate users without triggering a Basic Auth login prompt.

I've tagged this question with Apache 2.4 because I would prefer to solve this using Apache, but I'm open to other ideas as well.

Thanks in advance for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always do a bit of PHP magic to make it happen - that way you can directly tie into WordPress's authentication functions, and keep it up to date as WordPress is updated.

The necessary function to determine if someone is logged in is documented here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

This is untested/non-functional code so tweaks will be needed, but the jist is there:

```
    require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');

    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $url = $_REQUEST['url'];
        $transformedBackendURL = changeHostnameandStuff($url);
        $content = file_get_contents($url);
        // parse all links and forms actions and redirect back to this script
        $content = preg_replace("/some-smart-regex-here/i", "$1 or $2 smart replaces", $content);
        echo $content;
    } else {
        header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
        echo 'You are forbidden!';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried using WP authentication to tie into users who have already authenticated with WP. This code works to authenticate. However, unless I've missed something, the echo of the requested URL will again trigger the rewrite rule which first sent the browser to this php file.

Comment: The goal would be to use PHP as a reverse proxy - there are a number of libraries out there as well that would provide the actual reverse proxy functionality

Comment: I haven't yet considered using PHP as a reverse proxy so thanks for the idea. I looked at a fewlibraries last ngiht, but haven't had time to test them yet. I don't yet see how using PHP as a reverse proxy might both protect (not allow direct URL access) the web application AND verify user authentication from WordPress. I can see how it would do one OR the other. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Essentially the logic would be as follows - if is_wordpress_user_logged_in then execute reverse proxy code, else return 403. You would also need an apache2/nginx rule where all requests to a path are handled by a single index.php file (similar to how WordPress handles paths) .

Comment: This was very helpful in getting me to the solution I needed. One thing I added was that instead of a redirect to block direct access to the Kibana application (or any app on a custom port) I added lines to iptables to only allow traffic to that port ON localhost and FROM localhost. This removes the need to protect the app from direct access. Then, I used a PHP reverse proxy to pull the app pages in from localhost:port/app/page  (same localhost).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can send an encrypted key with the URL that has the username and ip ...etc then decrypt it and use curl to check the user info on the other server. I hope that this would give you some ideas